# SQL Injection question Nodejs MSSQL template literal

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I was about to change all/most of my SQL queries in Nodejs to stored procedure to make sure that it is safe against SQL injection. I am using [this](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql) Node-MSSQL library to write my queries

However, as I was reading through the documentation one more time, I found this:

> All values are automatically sanitized against SQL injection. This is
> because it is rendered as prepared statement, and thus all limitations
> imposed in MS SQL on parameters apply. e.g. Column names cannot be
> passed/set in statements using variables.

```
sql.connect(config).then(() => {
    return sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})
```

It is basically saying that if template literals are used it is safe against any SQL injection. I am a bit confused about how template literals help against SQL injection in this case. For example if I set the value variable to:

`value = ;DELETE FROM TABLE1`

How does it get sanitized?

Comment: The library that submits your SQL will pass it to prepare and execute, it will replace your {value} with a parameter. The injection risk comes from if you manually build the query by concatenating {value} into the statement text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your input is sanitized, what happens is your SQL statement becomes *parameterized*.

As an example, consider submitting `select * from table where name='Bob'`. Here the filtering is on a literal value, but you want to filter on a value you provide at runtime.

In your application you *could* dynamically build the statement to execute and doing so as an example using Dynamic-SQL might look like

```
declare @MyParameter nvarchar(10)=N'Bob'
declare @Sql nvarchar(100)

set @sql=N'select * from table where name=''' + @MyParameter + ''''
```

This results in `@Sql` containing the literal string *select * from table where name='Bob'*

And you could execute this using `exec sp_executesql @sql` which is essentially what happens when your sql text is submitted to the server from your application code.

However if your user input happens to be `Bob'; delete from SomeImportantTable;--` then the executed statement becomes

`select * from table where name='Bob'; drop table SomeImportantTable;--`

And that's valid syntax, SQL Server will duly return rows from `table` and immediately delete from `SomeImportantTable`.

If, however, the statement is *parameterized* then the variable is not concatenated but instead passed as a parameter value and the client library will replace the placeholder value in code with the appropriate parameter, like the following

```
declare @MyParameter nvarchar(10)=N'Bob''; delete from SomeImportantTable;--' 
/* Here the quotes are doubled as that's how you tell SQLServer it's a single quote in the string 
   instead of terminating the string*/
declare @Sql nvarchar(100)
        
set @Sql=N'select * from table where name=@p1'
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@p1 varchar(10)', @MyParameter
```

This time, the parameter value is not part of the parsed sql statement and instead SQL Server just uses the complete value as an argument to the seek/scan operator in the execution plan. Probably, no rows are returned and no rows are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have to sanitize and validate your user data yourself, before your query, that way if your value is a string or int, you have to check the data type and make sure you remove all HTML and XSS script.

Comment: No, you should *never* rely just on your own sanitization, there's always someone smarter at exploitation than you.

Answer (score 0):

The query function is what's known as a tag function. Note the lack of parenthesize in `` query`SELECT...` `` .

this article explains it better than I could.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).